# createRadialGradient with a circle centered on the bottom left of the bubble chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bubble-chart

I created a bubble chart with chart.JS 2.0 (risk matrix). I would now like to color the background with a green circle centered on the bottom left of the chart which would become red when expanding to the top right.

I managed to create the circle on the background which generates the following chart :

[image]

I would now like to have the circle centered on the bottom left but I am struggling to deal with the coordinates.

```js
    Chart.pluginService.register({
      beforeDraw: function(chart, easing) {
        if (chart.config.options.chartArea && chart.config.options.chartArea.backgroundColor) {
          var helpers = Chart.helpers;
          var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
          var chartArea = chart.chartArea;
          // {left: 45.073828125, top: 34.4, right: 588, bottom: 538.2}
          ctx.save();
          var canevas = document.querySelector("canvas");
          var contexte = canevas.getContext('2d');
          X = chartArea.right;
          Y = chartArea.bottom;
          leftoffset = chartArea.left;
          topoffset = chartArea.top;

          // var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 70, 70, 0);
          var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(X / 1.34, Y / 1.412, X / 8, X / 4 * 3, Y / 2, X / 3);

          gradient.addColorStop(0, "green");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "orange");
          gradient.addColorStop(1, "red");
          ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

          ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, chartArea.top, chartArea.right - chartArea.left, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);


        }
      }
    });


    var myBubbleChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("bubble-chart"), {
      type: 'bubble',
      data: {
        labels: "Africa",
        datasets: [{
            idu: 29,
            label: ["Hurricane"],
            backgroundColor: "#398B93",
            data: [{
              x: 4,
              y: 1,
              r: 15
            }]
          },

          {
            idu: 30,
            label: ["Flooding"],
            backgroundColor: "#398B93",
            data: [{
              x: 5,
              y: 4,
              r: 15
            }]
          },

          {
            idu: 31,
            label: ["Cyber-attack"],
            backgroundColor: "#398B93",
            data: [{
              x: 1,
              y: 4,
              r: 15
            }]
          },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        chartArea: {
          backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(0.25turn, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c)'
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Risk matrix'
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: "Likelihood"
            },
            ticks: {
              min: 0, // Controls where axis starts
              max: 6, // Controls where axis finishes
              stepSize: 1,
              display: true,
              callback: function(tick) {
                return (tick !== 0) && (tick !== 6) ? tick : '';
              }
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: true,
              drawBorder: false,
              lineWidth: 1, // Width of line,
              offsetGridLines: true,
              color: '#EBEEEE',

            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: "Impact"
            },
            ticks: {
              min: 0, // Controls where axis starts
              max: 6, // Controls where axis finishes
              stepSize: 1,
              display: true,

              callback: function(tick) {
                return (tick !== 0) && (tick !== 6) ? tick : '';
              }
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: true,
              drawBorder: false,
              offsetGridLines: true,
              color: '#ebeeee',
            }
          }]
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
          labels: {
            fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
          }
        },
        jitter: true,
      }
    });
```

```css
#bubble-chart {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bubble-chart" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

Thanks a lot